# the gradient in complex coordinates

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional complex manifold, or equivalently a $2n$ real manifold. Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric. Let $f\in C^\infty(M)$. What is $\nabla f$?

If $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n$ are real coordinates than I know $$\nabla f=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}g^{jk}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$ where I'm setting $x_{n+j}=y_j$. We can also extend the metric $g$ to $TM^\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that $$\nabla f=\sum_{j=1}^ng^{j\overline k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}?$$

What's the gradient in complex coordinates?